# FOSUserBundle login form and HWIOAuthBundle on the same page, and handling AccessDeniedExceptions

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

My problem in short is this: I have a page (`/check-in/:training_id/`) where the user can buy trainings. When they access this page and are not logged in I want to redirect them to the `/login` page where I've put FOSUserBundle's login form with some buttons logging the user in with HWIOAuthBundle (like `/connect/check-facebook` and such). Now before I've included HWIOAuthBundle everything worked fine. I've thrown an `AccessDeniedException` in the Controller, the user was redirected to the `/login` page, and when they logged in they were redirected to where they were (a.k.a `/check-in/:training_id/`).

But since I've added HWIOAuthBundle to my app the `AccessDeniedException` is now handled by HWIOAuthBundle, and the user is redirected to HWIOAut's login page, in my case `/connect`. The problem with this is that on that page I cannot simply add the login form from FOSUserBundle, because when I do that I get errors like `Variable last_username doesn't exist` or something like that.

(Btw. just to be clear I have copy-pasted the contents from the `/app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/security/login.html.twig` into the `/app/Resources/HWIOAuthBundle/views/Connect/login.html.twig` file, set `firewalls.main.oauth.login_path` to `/login` in the security.yml file).

So my question is how can I have a page that's controlled by the HWIOAuthBundle to display FOSUserBundle's login page, or if that's simpler, how can I make sure that on AccessDeniedExceptions the user is redirected to my `/login` page? (Simple `$this->redirectToRoute('/login')` will not suffice, because after logging in the user would be redirected to the homepage instead of the original page they were redirected to the login page from).

I'd appreciate any help with this :)